# how to get the peer count of each device in a WiFi-Direct environment

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

Upon **requestPeers()** or at the **discoverPeers()** I want to get the peer count of each device available, so that each device will have the peer counts of the devices, they can connect to.

Then I can call the **createGroup()** method in the device with highest peer count to make the WiFi-Direct group more efficient!

This is just an idea I came up with, is it possible to do?

if so how can I exchange the peer count among the device available?

Answer (score 1):

**For the first quesiton,** this is my experience.

I have two different devices A and B.

I have tried to set groupOwnerIntent on one of my devices, but it does not work as I thought.

No matter which one I set, A is always the GO.

The Wifi p2p spec said, Wifi Direct computes the GO intent and negotiates which device shall be the GO in the phase of peer discovery.

I think there shall be not only GO intent but also other attributes to determine the GO.

Maybe the GO intent works when the two devices are the same. I am not sure.

**For the second question,** I think you should connect them first to compute which device has the most number of available peer.

Comment: the device remembers the WiFi-Direct group when it connects for the first time, that's the reason A is always the GO. forgetting the network using WiFi-Direct settings could change the GO according to the **groupOwnerIntent** set.
in my knowledge, groupOwnerIntent is the only attribute determines the GO. by default, groupOwnerIntent = -1 indicates the system can choose an appropriate value, where GO will be randomly selected.

Comment: I think your answer for the 2nd question is pretty much accurate, since to exchange any kind of data the devices must be connected. 
what do you think about, exchanging peer count after connecting and then disconnect in order to create a new group with the device with highest peer count?
 will that introduce considerable amount of delay?